# What's the meaning of the scene when governor's wife carries eight cups of coffee during the speech of Governor Morris in Ides of March?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ides-of-march

At time 1:29:30 you can see a woman (Cindy Morris, governor's wife) carrying eight cups of coffee, whilst in the background you can hear the Governor's speech.

My question is what's the meaning/significance of this scene? What does it have to do with the speech or the plot?

*Footnote: The sound of this scene is the governor's speech, so Cindy's steps are not heard nor the ambience of the outside.*

*Found this on youtube, this is the part I'm talking about:*

Comment: I do not believe there is any deep significance to this. She has coffees for herself, her husband, the man who introduced him to the crowd, and five other people.

Comment: thanks @JamesMcLeod  idk, when I encountered this part, it felt like this scene wasn't supposed to be there.. mostly because it has no sound, I mean the only sound is the speech. The speech sound doesn't get lowered in that scene. Anyways I was just curious if anyone else would think this as an edition mistake.

Comment: Also I believe all scenes must have a purpose, I'm not sure if this one has any..